# How do you create an optimizer for the TD-Lambda method in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference

I am trying to implement TD-Gammon, as described in [this paper](https://www.bkgm.com/articles/tesauro/tdl.html), which uses the TD-Lambda learning algorithm . This has been done already [here](https://github.com/fomorians/td-gammon/blob/master/model.py), but it is 4 years old and doesn't use Tensorflow 2. I am trying to do this in Tensorflow 2 and think I need to create a custom optimizer to perform the weight change as described in the paper linked above.

I know that to create a custom optimizer, you need to subclass the Optimizer class and implement the `create_slots`, `resource_apply_dense`, `resource_apply_sparse`, and `get_config` methods. However, the weight change algorithm for TD-Lambda requires the neural network outputs (`Y_t-1` and `Y_t` in the paper) and the `resource_apply_dense` method doesn't seem to have access to that.

How do I access the neural network outputs? Or am I just going about this the wrong way?